# Use signalR class method in asp.net mvc controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr

I have method in my hub

```
public class auctionHub : Hub
{
    public static bool loop = true;
    public auctionHub()
    {

    }

    public void init(object auctions)
    {
        loop = true;
        while (loop)
        {
            List<Auction> auctionList = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<Auction>>(auctions.ToString());
            var auctionsToClient = auctionList.Select(m => new { m.Id, EndDate = ExtensionMethods.ToReadableTimeSpanString(m.EndDate - DateTime.Now) });
            context.Clients.Client(Context.ConnectionId).serverTime(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString(), auctionsToClient);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);

        }
    }
    public void setLoop(bool val)
    {
        loop = val;
    }
}
```

in View I have javascript method:

```
$('body').on('click', '#AuctionList .pagination a', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        success: function (result) {
            //ChangeUrl('index', url);
            //auctionHub.server.stop();
            $('#AuctionList').html(result);                
            auctionHub.server.init(newData);

        }
    });
});
```

In controller

```
public ActionResult Index(int? page,FormCollection form)
{
   //other code
    if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
    {
        //auctionHub.loop = false;
        DefaultHubManager hd = new DefaultHubManager(GlobalHost.DependencyResolver);
        var hub = hd.ResolveHub("auctionHub") as auctionHub;
        if (hub != null)
        {
            hub.setLoop(false);
        }
    }
//other code
}
```

And I have problem because when one user call method Index in controller and use hub methods hub.setLoop(false) and break loop, sometimes this also break loop for other users. I built real time auction system. I don't have idea, how I can repair it.

Comment: why would u set ur Loop becomes false in Index? please explain more about whats ur code about. whats your code goal?

Comment: adding to @mark question. your loop variable is static. Do you need to be static? ... static means it is shared for all requests coming from same user or even different users. if you want it to remain it's value only for each customer, you need to change your implementation.

Comment: @AKhudairy how I can do it? How I can read hub property for each customer?

Comment: @pepeb333 , please check my comment below. of course you need to read about threading and thread safe code in .net. It is better to understand also how the different threads are created for each request

Answer (score 0):

As your problem is with the loop boolean. You should not use static variable here. I don't understand what you want to do exactly, but consider doing this.

Create a dictionary which has a loop bool for each user. The key of the dictionary will be the connectionid (if you don't know how to get it, check the signalR documentation). The connectionid will remain same for all calls from the same user. The value of the dictionary will be a boolean (represents the loop variable).

Since you have multiple threads, working with the dictionary will require some knowledge of how to be thread safe with dictionaries. you can use concurrentdictionary to help. Check: [MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191(v=vs.110).aspx), and this [example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997369(v=vs.110).aspx)

the dictionary object make it as static variable. Then in your function, in any place you get or set the loop variable, you should get the value from the dictionary, and set it back to the dictionary. if the connection id doesn't exist then it means this is the first call from this user, so you should add it to the dictionary with the loop default value.

Sorry for not posting code, I hope the explanation is good enough.